# Is there any other way of doing this on windows apart "run flask"

Tags: python, flask

```
flask : The term 'flask' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was 
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.  
At line:1 char:1  
+ flask run
+ ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (flask:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I've been having this error for awhile now, is really frustrating, I want to create a server and I've installed the flask framework, but it's not working can someone please help me.

I tried `run flask` on the command line on my IDE (PyCharm) but it's not working, I want to create a server.

Comment: `python -m <scriptname>.py` might work

Comment: make sure that flask is installed and that you are using the right installation. Try to run the flask command in your cmd in the project root directory instead of the pycharm terminal

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas:
check flask installed

```
pip show flask
```

if not installed:

```
pip install flask
```

create a sample flask app `app.py`:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return 'Hello, World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

run the app:

```
python app.py
```

or export app in macos/linux:

```
export FLASK_APP=app
```

or export app in windows command prompt:

```
set FLASK_APP=app
```

run flask

```
flask run
```